# System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Causes in C#

Tags: c#, exception

Good day.

I'm new to C# and trying to call functions from a DLL (C++  ObjGen). I'm getting this message and can't figure out why. Here's the code:

```
object[] objID = new object[] { ID };

ObjGen.Invoke(InvokeEnum.Query_State, objID);
```

Dll code

///////////////////////

```
INVOKE_FUNC_IMPLEMENT(Query_State, CUtil::GetState)
```

///////////////////////

```
bool CUtil::GetState(InvokeEnum methodID, SAFEARRAY * psa)
{
    UNIT_ID UID = (UNIT_ID)PARAM_LONG(0);

    CUtil::Instance()->NotifyUpdateState(UID);
    for(int slot = 0; slot < SLOT_ID_MAX; slot++)
        g_CManager.m_PJAssociArray[UID][slot] = 0;

    return true;
}
```

There is a loop called the top Invoke function.
When objID = 1 Or 2 Or 3, the function worked very well.
But when objID = 4. the function exception.

What could be the reason?
Issue in C# or Dll file?

Is there something error in the Instance() OR NotifyUpdateState() ?
i can't do the judgement.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array of objects in which an object of ID is one element in that array. And you are passing it into a method, the said array `objID`

Can you include a code sample of what you are trying to achieve?

It is not very clear.

What is ID? Has ID been instantiated with the `new`? What is ObjGen?

Do you have the function 4 in your dll, if not that explains why you got a null reference exception. Double check your DLL and make sure you are calling the function 4.

Hope this helps you in giving you hints?
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Hello tommieb, I updated some DLL c++ code here.
btw, The ID = 4 is not a specially function in DLL file. 
It is only a array value.
thank you.

Comment: That is a COM object you are calling in the DLL? Maybe you need to check the method interop call, I noticed there is a SAFEARRAY, are you doing anything with that, maybe pass null into it on the C# side and see what happens?

Comment: @tom, Yes, this is a COM obj called in the DLL. I already found the root cause. The ObjGen not initialized finished when i try to invoke the DLL function. The ObjGen initialized at another thread. 
But the ObjGen.Invok generated by different thread. It is faster than the initialization thread.

Comment: @Nano HE: Great to hear you got your issue sorted! :) Good luck and take care! :)